# Can't access global variable inside of a usort() function call

Tags: php, function, scope, global-variables, usort

I'm trying to use `usort()` and leverage a global variable inside its function scope, but without success.

I've simplified my code down to bare bones to show what I mean:

```
$testglobal = 1;
function cmp($a, $b) {
    global $testglobal;
    echo 'hi' . $testglobal;
}
usort($topics, "cmp");
```

Assuming the `usort()` runs twice, my expectations is this will be the output:

```
hi1hi1
```

Instead, my output is:

```
hihi
```

I've read the manual (http://us.php.net/usort) and I don't see any limitations on accessing global variables. If I assign the `usort()` to a variable that I echo, it outputs 1, so the `usort()` is definitely running successfully (plus, there are all those "hi's").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't reproduce the "error" and neither can codepad: http://codepad.org/5kwctnDP

You could also use object properties instead of global variables

```
<?php
class Foo {
    protected $test = 1;
    public function bar($a, $b) {
        echo 'hi' . $this->test;
        return strcmp($a, $b);
    }
}


$topics = array(1,2,3);
$foo = new Foo;
usort($topics, array($foo, 'bar'));
```

Answer (score 2):

The code I put in my question was dropped inside a template on bbPress, which is the forum cousin to Wordpress. A friend told me that "Sometimes PHP will act weird if you don't global a variable before you define it, depending on how nested the code is when it's executed - bbPress does some complex includes by the time the template outputs".

So I tried that and it works:

```
global $hi123;
$hi123 = ' working ';
```

I'm answering my own question in case another idiot like me finds this in a Google search. :-)

I'm going to accept VolkerK's answer, though, because the object workaround is pretty clever.

Comment: Thanks, Bobbyh! That fixed my issue with not being able to access global variables from within a function, either using the global keyword in the function or using the $GLOBALS superarray. It must have something to do with PHP setting scope on include'd files.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you access the variable using the super-global [`$GLOBALS`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) array?

```
$testglobal = 1;
function cmp($a, $b) {
    echo 'hi' . $GLOBALS['testglobal'];
}
usort($topics, "cmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working as of php 5.2.4

```
$testglobal = ' WORKING ';
$topics = array('a','b','c');      
function cmp($a, $b) {
    global $testglobal;
    echo 'hi' . $testglobal;
}
usort($topics, "cmp");
// hi WORKING hi WORKING
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not define variables as `global` or access `$GLOBALS` as a work around -- these are code smells in modern applications and deteriorate the scoped control of variables in general.

For applications below PHP7.4 (and in 2023, you shouldn't be using outdated versions), you can permit access to global variables via `use ($theGlobalVariable)` after the function signature.

For applications enjoying PHP7.4 or higher, "arrow function syntax" allows a global variable to be read inside the function scope.

Here is a demonstration of leveraging a globally-scoped lookup array from inside of a `usort()` call.  This is a very practical example that can be commonly found in professional codebases to perform a custom sort.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/fmHF4))

```
$lookup = [
    'foo' => 1,
    'bar' => 2,
    'baz' => 3,
    'fizz' => 4,
    'buzz' => 5,
];

$array = ['buzz', 'foo', 'baz'];
// sort $array ascending according to its mapped value
usort($array, fn($a, $b) => $lookup[$a] <=> $lookup[$b]);
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'foo',
  1 => 'baz',
  2 => 'buzz',
)
```