# Cant access global variable in function

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [can't access global variables inside a usort function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894990/cant-access-global-variables-inside-a-usort-function)

I've experienced this problem more then one time now, and I this time I couldnt figure out how to get around it.

```
$testing = "hej";
function compare($b, $a)
{
    global $testing;
    echo '<script>alert(\'>'.$testing.'<\');</script>';
}
```

Why does this not show a alertbox with ">hej<", for me it shows "><".

Also, this is a function that is call from `uasort` as second parameter.

Comment: Pass it as an argument through the compare() function... http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: It's a sign to stop using the `global` keyword. :)

Comment: try `var_dump($testing);` right after `global $testing;` what is the output?

Comment: The problem is, as I just added that I use it for compare in uasort, so..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple: **don't use globals.**

If you want access to that variable, and to change the value of that variable, pass it as a parameter by reference:

```
<?php
$testing = "hej";

function compare($b, $a, &$testing) {
    $testing = "def";
}

compare(1, 2, $testing);

echo $testing; // result: "def"
```

If you just want the value, pass it by value:

```
<?php
$testing = "hej";

function compare($b, $a, $testing) {
    $testing = "def";
}

compare(1, 2, $testing);

echo $testing; // result: "hej"
```

**Update:**

Another option is to pass an object to `usort()` in an array:

```
<?php
class mySort {
    public $testing;

    public function compare($a, $b) {
        echo '<script>alert(\'>'.$this->testing.'<\');</script>';
    }
}

$data = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$sorter = new mySort();
usort($data, array($sorter, 'compare'));
```

Comment: I could gladly stop using it, if you showed me how I can acheive what I want without it. I cannot just call compare with a third argument since I use uasort.

Comment: Ah, I see. Have you taken a look at the "duplicate" question? The accepted answer there says to use an object, and call its member variables: http://stackoverflow.com/a/895023/1338999

Comment: @DavidEverlöf I updated my answer to include the object-oriented solution.

Comment: Yeah, just did it myself aswell, thank you though!